# Scalar multiplication of tensors

Tags: tensorflow.js

In TensorFlow Core for Python there is an operation called `tf.math.scalar_mul`.

I would like to scale tensors in TensorFlow.js. By trying for instance `a * 0.1` I get an error message (at least from Typescript):`The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.ts(2362)`.

Is scaling tensors applicable without making them arrays, scale elementwise then transform back to tensors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though, `tf.scalar` can be used, one can also use direclty `tensor.mul(number)` like the following

```
tf.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4]).mul(5).print(); // [5, 10, 15, 20]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in the [API documentation](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#mul). For multiplying a tensor `a` with 5, just `a.mul(tf.scalar(5))`.